# PHP prepared statement cannot work.And I don't know what is going wrong

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

Code below here cannot work.And I don't know where  the problem is:

```
 $insert_str="insert into User(Name,Password)values(?,?)";
 $stmt->$conn->prepare($insert_str);
 $stmt->bind_param("ss",$name,$password);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->close();
```

I can gurantee that mysql connection and mysql configuration are ok.Because code like this works:

```
$insert_str="insert into User(Name,Password)values('$name','$password')";
 $conn->query($insert_str);
 echo "Create Account Successfully";
```

Could someone help please? I have being considering potential problems for over 2 hours but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the variable $stmt as the return from the prepare statement, like this:

```
 $insert_str="insert into User(Name,Password)values(?,?)";
 $stmt=$conn->prepare($insert_str);
 $stmt->bind_param("ss",$name,$password);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->close();
```

Comment: My apology. I just ignore the basic syntax like-> and =. Now it works.Thank you so much.

Comment: no problem - simple mistake and not necessarily easy to spot when you have been staring at it for so long. Check the error logs each time something fails to work as you would expect...!